# Any free online issue/feature tracking software for small scale independent dev?

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

I'm going to be creating a few small mobile applications and have managed to find a great online Git repo hosting services that is free. It even comes with online issue tracking software but appears to be mainly geared towards the development team. I was hoping it would also have an interface for end-users to log issues/features and allow them to vote on what they wanted but it does not have this. It does expose an RESTful API but I didn't want to go down that path and wanted something ready to go (once configured).

I don't think I need it to be integrated with the Git repo so having something that is purely standalone would be great but I would definitely want something that is online as I don't want to install software on my local PC.

In summary, my requirements are:

1. Free or very cheap
2. Simple end-user interface to allow users
   to submit issues/features
3. Allow end-users to vote on their own or other users issues/features
4. Visible status of issues/features (i.e. whether they are pending, in progress, rejected, fixed etc)
5. A more advanced management system for me as a developer to manage the
   issues
6. Some basic reports/charts/graphing would be great
7. Email/RSS notification of new issues/suggestions would be great too
8. Something that is ready to go after some configuration/settings.

Can anyone recommend something that would be suitable for this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I based my question on a website I saw a while back but couldn't find it. Anyway, I've now found it again (it's called http://www.uservoice.com/). It's not really issue tracking but more of a way of letting end-users report features and allow them to vote on them. The important thing is that it is a very user friendly interface which is perfect for end-users. Obviously, I would then need to maintain issues/features in my own system (e.g. Mantis) and then manually sync features requested in uservoice to Mantis but that shouldn't be a big issue. Anyway, this perfectly meets my needs for my low volume applications at the moment.